# Import in CosmoTransitions

Tags: python

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ModuleNotFoundError                       Traceback (most recent call last)
Cell In[1], line 2
      1 from os import cpu_count
----> 2 import scanner
      4 '''
      5 
      6 This script executes scanner.py with the simple task of checking whether the model defined in tl_dark_photon_model.py can give observable stochastic gravitational wave signals
   (...)
     10 
     11 '''
     14 # Set the names of the model parameters and their respective default values

ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'scanner'
```

I try suggestions from chatgpt.

Comment: `scanner` is not a built-in python module.  You have to install it yourself.  Did you install it?

Answer (score 0):

The [documentation](https://pypi.org/project/scanner)
explains that you should

```
$ pip install scanner
```

You don't *have* to follow those directions.
But it will make a difference for whether

```
$ python -c 'import scanner'
```

completes successfully.